# Java Generics use class Object for the type of data they store, true or false? Please explain

Tags: java, generics

I actually do not understand this question. what I thought is that Generics can be substitute by any types of data which including both primitive and reference. How does the java generics relates to Object type?

Comment: I think that what's asking is how Generics are implemented under the hood, please check type erasure: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Comment: All generic types extend Object, because all reference types extend Object. Generics cannot store primitive types.

Answer (score 1):

Java generics do not allow using primitive types as generic parameters. At least in current versions, this may change in Java 9 with value types.

Anyway, the answer is false, although in many cases it's true. If you write:

```
class Foo<T> {
...
```

it means that Java will use `Object` internally at any place where the code refers to `T`. However:

```
class Foot<T extends InputStream> {
...
```

In the sample above the basic object is `InputStream`, therefore Java will use `InputStream` at any place where the code refers to `T`.

You can actually find this information even with reflection. With reflection there will be always the basic type. If you don't use `extends` for generic, the default type is `Object`.

Comment: Value types won't be in Java 9.  The list of features is here: http://openjdk.java.net/projects/jdk9/ and the project is well past the "feature complete" deadline.

Answer (score 0):

> Java Generics use class Object for the type of data they store, true or false?

The answer is false.

Java generics *can* use the class `Object` for the type, but they can also use a more specific type.  It depends on how the generic class is declared.

> what I thought is that Generics can be substitute by any types of data which including both primitive and reference.

That is incorrect.  You cannot use a primitive type as a generic type parameter in Java.

> How does the java generics relates to Object type?

That is too broad a question to answer here.

- I suggest you read the Oracle Java Tutorial stream on generics:  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/
- The Tutorial page on Type Erasure might answer your (real) question: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html